Build Moveit2 demo encounter error:Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gz_plugin_vendor]
I am learning Moveit2,following this site:
https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started.html
I use ubuntu22.04,ros2 humble,gazebo Fortress
But when I exec this intro in the website above:
sudo apt update && rosdep install -r --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y

There is an error:
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
    gz_ros2_control: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gz_plugin_vendor]
    Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
    #All required rosdeps installed successfully

Then if I exec:
cd ~/ws_moveit
    
colcon build --mixin release

More Error :
--- stderr: gz_ros2_control                                            
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findgz_sim_vendor.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "gz_sim_vendor", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gz_sim_vendor"
  with any of the following names:

    gz_sim_vendorConfig.cmake
    gz_sim_vendor-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gz_sim_vendor" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gz_sim_vendor_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "gz_sim_vendor" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.

So,how to fix it

Welcome at RSE.
You have to use the correct version for your ROS distro. You are using humble, where gz_sim_vendor (and gz_ros2_control) is not released.
I guess using this branch should work then.

Thanks!It works

You're welcome. Please mark the question as solved then

Thanks! This worked.
