gz_ros2_control: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gz_plugin_vendor]
I'm learning ros2_control but I'm getting the following error while trying to run rosdep install:
Command:
rosdep install -r  -y -i --from-paths .

Error:
gz_ros2_control: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gz_plugin_vendor]

I am running ros2 humble on ubuntu 22.04, and Gazebo Classic
I would really appreciate a detailed answer because I'm new to ROS and don't have much context. Thanks

I saw a very similar question here: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/112513/42571, but I could not understand the answer

Basically the same answer once again:
I assume you want to build gz_ros2_control from source (why else would you run rosdep), which means that you have to use the correct branch from the repo of gz_ros2_control (this is humble for humble distro)
More info in the compatibility table here
